# Atom: How do I create shortcut to select a word and search?

Tags: atom-editor

I got really used to `cmnd+d, cmnd+g` and `cmnd+d, cmnd+shift+g` workflow in sublime text. Is it possible to reproduce the same behavior in Atom using `keymap.cson` or some other tool?

Here is step by step description of the expected behavior:

1. I put my cursor on a word.
2. I press `cmnd+d`, the word gets highlighted and silently copied to search input. Not silently would be ok.
3. If I press `cmnd+g`, the selection goes to the next occurrence of the word. If I press `cmnd+shift+g`, the selection goes to the previous occurrence of the word.
4. If I press `cmnd+d`, I select the current and the next occurrence of the word.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Linux instead of Mac and I'm not sure what the differences are, but here's the closest method I've found:

1. Put your cursor on a word
2. Press Ctrl+F3 to select the next occurrence of the term or Ctrl+Shift+F3 to select the previous occurrence

   - I say "term" instead of "word" because its behaviour depends on whether whole word matches are enabled in the Ctrl+F menu.
3. Press Ctrl+D once to select the current word, and again to select the next occurrence of the word

Also:

- Ctrl+F searches for whatever's selected
- Alt+F3 selects all occurrences of the current word